# In sailsjs / passport.js: How to get logged in user as object in a view?

Tags: session, sails.js, passport.js

I want to output the Username in a view, so I need to get the user object.

In

```
req.session.passport.user
```

there is only the user id (numeric), and

```
req.user
```

is undefined. Isn't use user stored as object in the session?

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this somewhere (in the connect & register function of service/protocols/local.js if you used sails-generate-auth)

```
Passport.create({
  protocol : 'local'
, password : password
, user     : user.id
}, function (err, passport) {
...
```

So just add the username here

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your policy.

I got this working by making a change in APP_ROOT/config/policies.js

```
  UserController: {
    me: ['passport']
  },

  HomeController: {
   '*': ['passport']
  }
```

After this for all views under User and Home controller can access user object.
Example:

```
<p>Hi <%=res.locals.user.username%></p>
```